# Operation was interrupted before it could finish

Tags: apt

I was trying to install surface-linux (https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup) on my Ubuntu 21.04 setup. When I was running "sudo apt install linux-image-surface linux-headers-surface iptsd libwacom-surface" I accidentally clicked ctrl+c. I have uploaded my output onto Pastebin (https://pastebin.com/rrb5kAhc). Is there any way to finish the operation, or am I screwed?

Comment: I'd normally repeat the `apt install` command, but expect it to complain & offer suggestions which include --fix-broken options like `sudo apt -f install` (less typing than the entire --fix-broken) or if it suggests it, run the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` as suggested.  In rare cases I might jump straight to them, but I'd base that on where it was up to during the installation..   (I've not looked at your pastebin detail)

Comment: Thanks heaps for the suggestion, it responded by saying that those packages are already installed (see: pastebin.com/cz9tWgkE) when I retyped the apt install command